# How to show Cross sell products even if the main product isn't in cart?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2.6, cross-sells

I'm using `Magento-2.2.6`

I am showing cross sell product in `product_detailed_info` with success.

The only problem is that cross sell product are shown only if the "main" product is in cart.

How can I show cross sell product even if the "main" product isn't in cart ? Do I have to modify Crosssell.php or something like that ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

We can get cross sell products of a current product by using the following function, regardless of product added in cart or not

```
$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$crossSellProducts = $currentProduct->getCrossSellProducts();
foreach ($crossSellProducts as $crossSellProduct) {
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that it works in Magento-2.2.6 ?

Comment: I implemented this in one my project. For me it is working. What error you are getting?

Comment: Where I have to add this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your template file,

```
$myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\CrossSellItems');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct();

 if ($currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct()) {
$crossSellProducts = $currentProduct->getCrossSellProducts();

  if (!empty($crossSellProducts)) {

    ?>

    <div class="category-right product-parts">
        <h2><span id="_CrossSellDisplay_TitleLabel">Cross Sell Products</span></h2>

        <div class="row">
            <?php
            $store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
            foreach ($crossSellProducts as $crossSellProduct) {

                $product = $this->getLoadProduct($crossSellProduct->getId());


                $imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();

                ?>
                <li class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="sub-cat-tile">
                        <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl ?>">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="subcat-title">
                        <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $product->getName() ?></a>
                    </h4>
                    <p>
                        <?php $product->getPrice() ?>
                    </p>

                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php

} else
{ echo "<div class=\"category-right product-parts\">No Product Found!</div>"; }
```

}

?>

In your module create Block/Product/CrossSellItems.php class and add the following,

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product;
class CrossSellItems extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
protected $_registry; protected $_productloader;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getCurrentProduct()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}

public function getLoadProduct($id)
{
    return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
}
```

}